# List.setAdapter(adapter) in FragmentActivity throwing an error with spinners

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-fragmentactivity

Any help is appreciated. I am still learning Android and have looked through a lot of questions but can't seem to find the solution. Again, thanks for helping!

I am getting an error where I cannot get properly set up my ArrayAdapter in a FragmentActivity in the setupeverything method. I have spinners providing years and terms, but I do not know why list.setAdapter is throwing an error...
Here is the code I have so far...

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


private ViewPager _mViewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter _adapter;
variables here...



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setUpView();
    setupeverything();    //LINE 49
}

private void setUpView(){
    _mViewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    _adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getSupportFragmentManager());
    _mViewPager.setAdapter(_adapter);
    _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}

public static void refreshview()
{
    int year = spinner_year.getSelectedItemPosition();
    int term = spinner_term.getSelectedItemPosition();

    listofclasses.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<terms[year][term].getSize();i++)
    {
       listofclasses.add(terms[year][term].getCourse(i).getname() + "   " + terms[year][term].getCourse(i).getcredits()+ "   " + terms[year][term].getCourse(i).getgrade());

    }
    adapterthing.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setcreditandgpa();
}
public void buttonaddclass(View view)
{
    int year = spinner_year.getSelectedItemPosition();
    int term = spinner_term.getSelectedItemPosition();
    terms[year][term].addClass("test"+count, "B+", 4);

    refreshview();  
    //Intent openaddclass = new Intent("AddClassActivity");
    //startActivity(openaddclass);   //Removed because changed to fragments

}

public void setupeverything()
{
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_classes);
adapterthing = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listofclasses);
    list.setAdapter(adapterthing);    //LINE 245
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {
            deleteclass(position);

          return true;

        }});


    array_year=new String[5];
    array_year[0]="1";
    array_year[1]="2";
    array_year[2]="3";
    array_year[3]="4";
    array_year[4]="5";
    spinner_year = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_year);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_year);
    spinner_year.setAdapter(adapter);

    array_term=new String[4];
    array_term[0]="F";
    array_term[1]="W";
    array_term[2]="S";
    array_term[3]="S";

    spinner_term = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_term);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_term);
    spinner_term.setAdapter(adapter1);

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j<4;j++)
      {
        terms[i][j] = new ClassList();
      }
    }

    spinner_year.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            refreshview();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    });
    spinner_term.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            refreshview();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    edittotalcredit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_credits);
    edittermcredit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_credits_term);
    edittotalgpa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_gpa);
    edittermgpa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_gpa_term);


}
```

LogCat:

```
05-29 00:40:31.415    2713-2713/?                              E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.drexel.drexelgpacalc/com.drexel.drexelgpacalc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.drexel.drexelgpacalc.MainActivity.setupeverything(MainActivity.java:245)
    at com.drexel.drexelgpacalc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    ... 11 more
```

XML Layouts:

activity_main.xml is the first fragment to be shown to display data from chosen course lists from addclasslayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
 >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_year"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_term"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_classes"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="4" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_submit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Add Class"
    android:onClick="buttonaddclass" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_credits_term"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Credits This Term:"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_credits_term"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint=" "
        android:longClickable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_gpa_term"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="GPA This Term:"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_gpa_term"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint=" "
        android:longClickable="false" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_credits"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Credits Overall:"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_credits"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint=" "
        android:longClickable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_gpa"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="GPA Overall:"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_gpa"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint=" "
        android:longClickable="false" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager" />


</LinearLayout>
```

AddClassLayout.xml   Second Fragment which pulls data from a list and supposed to send into listofclasses.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buttonclick"
    android:text="Add Class" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3.5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Start Entering Class Here"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:singleLine="true"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:hint="Grade"
    android:entries="@array/gradeArray" />
</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
</ListView>
```

Comment: line number:49 which one can you highlighted

Comment: listofclasses is what?

Comment: in mainactivity.java line number 49 you get nullPointer Excep.. : com.drexel.drexelgpacalc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)

Comment: You should check your main.xml layout to see if listview_classes is actually defined in this file.

Comment: @LionelPort  What do you mean by defined? I will include xml files.

Comment: From your code, in the main.xml layout file there must be a list view defined like: <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_classes"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>. It's possible the id your using has actually be defined in a different layout file.

Comment: Line 49 is not very interesting; you'll want to look at line 245, which should be somewhere in the `setupeverything()` method. The NPE already indicates that one of variables isn't (or couldn't be) initialised and hence is still `null` when you're trying to call a method on it.

Comment: @MH. Line 245 is denoted in the setupeverything() method

Comment: @SimonAgeyev: Yes, I know, that's what I said and what your stacktrace says too. The exact error happens on that line, so that's where you'll want to look. If I were to venture a guess: it's probably one of the class members that you haven't included in your snippet.

Comment: You have setContentView(R.layout.main), should be setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) if you want R.id.listview_class to be resolved by findById.

Comment: @LionelPort That works,but now my first fragment is empty, regardless of where I put my ViewPager xml code in the activity_main.xml.  This has somewhat helped the original problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments.

In the `onCreate` you have `setContentView(R.layout.main)` but `main.xml` doesn't have a listview defined in it with the id "listview_classes".

You have a view pager but I don't see anywhere where you use `R.layout.activity_main`. You need to be using a `layoutinflater` to setup `R.layout.activity_main` and set it on the view pager or just ditch the whole idea of a view pager.

It looks like it would be simpler to just `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` and remove the code about the view pager unless you have other reasons for wanting it there.

Comment: Well originally I was using an activity to populate my listofclasses, our team decided to try and get swipe views going so that is why it may seem messed up right now. I have Java classes that inflate them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `listofclasses` without instantiation. Thus getting `NullPointerException`.

**BTW**

Are you calling `refreshview()` method to populate your vector?

Answer (score 0):

this is because your listOfClasses that you pass to an array adapter is null.
you got to fill this list before you are passing it there... try this solution...

Simply you NullPointerException

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.drexel.drexelgpacalc.MainActivity.setupeverything(MainActivity.java:245)
at com.drexel.drexelgpacalc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
```

just click twice the line

```
at com.drexel.drexelgpacalc.MainActivity.setupeverything(MainActivity.java:245)
```

and eclipse will show you where the trouble is.
and you'll got to recognize what variable has null value..
think it's a list_of_classes.

LogCat is a powerfull toll for developers ;)

Comment: Yes, the line is shown in the code and I have included it. It is the 3rd line of code in the setupeverything() method.